# How to Append HTML to Body While Staying Relative to Another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My situation is that I must append a `div` called `#tooltip` to the `body`, so that it stays on top of all other `div`s (`z-index` will not work in my case). At the same time, its position has to stay relative to another `div`, `#draggable-div`, due to draggable. In other words, when I drag `#draggable-div` around, `#tooltip` will also move with `#draggable-div`.

Here is the html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Some Div</div>
        <div id="draggable-div" class="draggable">New Div Position Should Be Relative to Me</div>
        <div>Some More Div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jquery:

```
var alert = '<div id="tooltip"><div id="tooltiptext"><h4>Not Ready Yet!</h4></div></div>';
$("body").append(alert);
```

However, how would I go about setting `#tooltip`'s position to be relative to `#draggable-div` while appending to `body`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this link: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip

Comment: This is the XY problem. Append it inside `#draggable-div` and don't establish any stacking context on `#draggable-div`.

Comment: At the startDrag event add some class to your draggable div and make #tooltip relative to this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you append to `body`, it's always going to be the last element. You want to append it as neighbor to the draggable element, like this:

```
var alert = $('<div id="tooltip"><div id="tooltiptext"><h4>Not Ready Yet!</h4></div></div>');

alert.insertAfter($("#draggable-div"));
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/21b26ufk/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should change append by prepend.

```
$("body").prepend(alert);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/s588yfz1/

Check the documentation for prepend, you can use prependTo as well.
http://api.jquery.com/prepend/